# Pass error message JSON to another page template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, angular-ui-router

Am new to angular js.(A week old). I have a requirement were am using $http to send a request.I want to display the error that is received in the response message in another page ,but am not able to figure out how to pass the value to another page.The controller of the new page is different from the one that is making http calls.Below is the code that i have written.Nothing seems to be working.Please guide me on how to go about with this requirement?

```
    $http({
           method   : 'POST',
           url      : 'http://localhost:8080/abc/users',
           data     : JSON.stringify(toPass)
        }).then(function (data) {
            // this callback will be called asynchronously
            // when the response is available
            console.log(data.data+'a');
            $scope.result="The request has been successfully submitted" +data.data.emailId;
            $scope.x=data.data.emailId;
            console.log('result'+x);
            console.log('result');
            //$location.path('/Success?{error1}');
            window.location="/Success?{x}";
            /*if (data.data.error){
                $scope.error=data.data.error
            }else{
                $scope.result=data.data.emailId;
            }*/
          }, function (error) {
            // called asynchronously if an error occurs
            // or server returns response with an error status.
            console.log("An error encountered"+error);

            var error1=error.status;

        // $location.path('/Success?{error1}');

          });
   }
 })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make Services Like this

```
 app.service(
            "friendService",
            function( $http, $q ) {
                // Return public API.
                return({
                    addFriend: addFriend,
                    getFriends: getFriends,
                    removeFriend: removeFriend
                });
                // ---
                // PUBLIC METHODS.
                // ---
                // I add a friend with the given name to the remote collection.
                function addFriend( name ) {
                    var request = $http({
                        method: "post",
                        url: "api/index.cfm",
                        params: {
                            action: "add"
                        },
                        data: {
                            name: name
                        }
                    });
                    return( request.then( handleSuccess, handleError ) );
                }
                // I get all of the friends in the remote collection.
                function getFriends() {
                    var request = $http({
                        method: "get",
                        url: "api/index.cfm",
                        params: {
                            action: "get"
                        }
                    });
                    return( request.then( handleSuccess, handleError ) );
                }
                // I remove the friend with the given ID from the remote collection.
                function removeFriend( id ) {
                    var request = $http({
                        method: "delete",
                        url: "api/index.cfm",
                        params: {
                            action: "delete"
                        },
                        data: {
                            id: id
                        }
                    });
                    return( request.then( handleSuccess, handleError ) );
                }
                // ---
                // PRIVATE METHODS.
                // ---
                // I transform the error response, unwrapping the application dta from
                // the API response payload.
                function handleError( response ) {
                    // The API response from the server should be returned in a
                    // nomralized format. However, if the request was not handled by the
                    // server (or what not handles properly - ex. server error), then we
                    // may have to normalize it on our end, as best we can.
                    if (
                        ! angular.isObject( response.data ) ||
                        ! response.data.message
                        ) {
                        return( $q.reject( "An unknown error occurred." ) );
                    }
                    // Otherwise, use expected error message.
                    return( $q.reject( response.data.message ) );
                }
                // I transform the successful response, unwrapping the application data
                // from the API response payload.
                function handleSuccess( response ) {
                    return( response.data );
                }
            }
        );
```

Comment: Thank you for your help Wasiq. I used your code as base and created a service.

Answer (score 0):

Sharing data over controllers can be done by either a shared parent controller or (imho better) by using a service where you store the data. Services are singletons in AngularJs and are a good fit for this.